# jQuery framework internals

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to understand the internals of how jquery framework is written and finding it hard to understand the code.

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding a good way to get started.

Thanks for all the useful input. Editing the topic since I had limited space for adding individual comments.
I have written a lot of basic javascript code. 
I know basic DOM, have used event handlers, know CSS basics. I have read about many of the topics you have mentioned and I am familiar with it although not an expert and have not coded some of the advanced topics like closures. Here are the books I have used so far Head first javascript - good in the beginning as a starter.
Books my friends have recommended and I use regularly are Javascript - The Definitive Guide, Javascript - The good parts (I read this a while ago and it was hard for me at the time).
My friend just recommended Secrets of Javascript Ninja - John Resig. Seems like a good one.
I ordered the Javascript Design patterns book you recommend last week

I have read the https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript you pointed me to. I will checkout some of the other resources you pointed me to.

Let me think a little more regarding if I want to do a little more reading before I post specific questions I have on jquery.

Thanks
Susan

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To comprehend the actual source would require some degree of Javascript knowledge - If you don't already know what's going on then you basically need to learn more Javascript.

Key things to learn:

- Prototypal inheritance ( the
  inheritance used in ECMAScript, the
  core language on which Javascript is
  based upon )
- Lambdas ( inline functions )
- Closures ( outer variables from outer scope accessible from inner functions )
- Regular expressions ( used for matching the selector strings fed to jQuery )
- DOM ( The DOM API which is used to interact with markup languages )

When learning, use Firebug so you can evaluate your expressions interactively and immediately see what's going on

An excellent free resource for learning that I would recommend:
http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html

If you're a beginner to DOM Scripting/Javascript:

- [http://www.amazon.com/DOM-Scripting-Design-JavaScript-Document/dp/1590595335/ref=sr_1_19?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1252905196&sr=1-19](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595335)

If you're intermediate level:

- [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0596517742/ref=s9_simz_gw_s0_p14_i3?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=0KCJ77GKHPREBFD3WAKG&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=470938631&pf_rd_i=507846](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

If you're past intermediate level and want to be an expert:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Wrox-Guides/dp/0764579088](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764579088)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-JavaScript-Techniques-John-Resig/dp/1590597273/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1252905139&sr=1-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597273)
- [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Design-Patterns-Recipes-Problem-Solution/dp/159059908X/ref=sr_1_16?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1252905196&sr=1-16](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059908X)

Other technical references:

- http://www.w3.org/DOM/
- http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript

If you have specific questions about a certain code snippet just ask here. Another resource that I can recommend for more advanced questions would be the jQuery mailing list or irc://irc.freenode.net/jquery where jresig hangs out himself and comes by and answers questions. There are other guru ops who reside there like ajpiano/paulirish/nlogax.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Please refer my original question above. Sorry did not have sufficient space to add comment

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for insight about how jQuery is written, the uncompressed source code is pretty readable.  There are a few books mentioned in [SO74884](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books) that are worth a read.  Resig's book doesn't really cover jQuery at all, but is good about teaching object oriented javascript.

If you are having a problem understanding something in jQuery's code (why it was done/how it works), you should post a question with some code bits to Stack Overflow, asking for some help understanding it.

Comment: Thanks for the link which points to useful resources. I have used many of the resources pointed out in that link. Let me think a little more regarding if I want to do a little more reading before I post specific questions I have on jquery

Answer (score 2):

Why not learn from the man himself, John Resig, here : http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Based on that, I'd definitely get the book your friend suggested.

You can also find some more nice resources on his website, courtesy of [googling site:ejohn.org/apps](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aejohn.org%2Fapps)

Answer (score 0):

I was also like you interested in how jQuery works internally, I've spent some time learning from jQuery code source and trying to understand the core architecture, then I've created a github repo [how-jQuery-works](https://github.com/AmraniCh/how-jQuery-works) to share my knowledge that I've acquired with other developers, hope you learn something from this repository.