# Is there a document that explains jQuery's code?

Tags: jquery

I have been going through the core jQuery code and had a few "why did they do it like that" moments.

Now, I'm in no way that great at JavaScript programming, but some things seemed a little different in jQuery than what I would usually do. I know they probably have to think more about optimisations then readability etc, but I am still confused about some things.

I was wondering if there was an online document that documents some of the core code? I know there are comments in there, but something more than that I would find beneficial.

No offence intended to anyone that works on the library!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at the code much for jQuery, but John Resig is one of the main people involved with it, and he references it in his this book, so it may help to explain some of why they made decisions they did:
Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja
http://www.manning.com/resig/

Answer (score 1):

No comprehensive overview that I know of, but I listed some learning materials to up your JS skill so you can comprehend better @ [jQuery framework internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419731/jquery-framework-internals/1419777#1419777)

Comment: You do have a great answer there - voting both up :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good one

[Visual jQuery](http://visualjquery.com/)

[jQuery documentation (CHM)](http://charupload.wordpress.com/2007/12/07/jquery-documentation-chm/)

Comment: I knew about this site, however I was looking for something that goes in depth into the actual code itself. Thanks for your answer.