# How can I simplify my code for my Javascript "show/hide on DIV" function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have read the entire W3schools Javascript tutorial (basic and advanced) more than 3 times. I have read the HTML/CSS tutorials countless times. I have also read several postings on this site regarding sho/hide features. I have tried using Javascript variables but I get bugs.

**Absolutely NO Jquery, Javascript ONLY please.**

My markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/showerHider.js"></script>

<div id="wrappernav"> </div>

<div class="container">
   <a id="btntxt" href="javascript:showerHider(document.getElementById('wrappernav'))">HIDE NAVIGATION</a>
   <a id="btn" href="javascript:showerHider(document.getElementById('wrappernav'))"></a>
</div>
```

I am a minimalist coder and want to simplify my `showerHider` Javascript function and the attributes of my markup. I have a `<div id="wrappernav">` navigation that transitions vertically out of screeen when the user clicks one of two **CLOSE** buttons that are nested inside another `<div class="container">`. When the `wrappernav` transitions the two buttons are moved and become **SHOW** buttons to give the user the option to... well you can see where this is going...

My external Javascript:

```
function showeHider(floater)
{
floater.style.webkitTransition = "margin-top .25s ease-in-out 0s" ;

if (floater.style.marginTop == "-345px" )
  {
  floater.style.marginTop = "25px" ;
  document.getElementById("btntxt") .innerHTML = "HIDE NAVIGATION" ;
  document.getElementById("btntxt") .style.top = "-370px" ;
  document.getElementById("btntxt") .style.left = "162px" ;
  document.getElementById("btn") .style.top = "-300px" ;
  document.getElementById("btn") .style.left = "135px" ;
  }

else
  {
  floater.style.marginTop = "-345px" ;
  document.getElementById("btntxt") .innerHTML = "SHOW NAVIGATION" ;
  document.getElementById("btntxt") .style.top = "20px" ;
  document.getElementById("btntxt") .style.left = "490px" ;
  document.getElementById("btn") .style.top = "17px" ;
  document.getElementById("btn") .style.left = "450px" ;
  }
}
```

Currently I have Javascript in the `onclick` attribute of the **CLOSE/SHOW** buttons which ties the buttons to the `showerHider` function. I want to simplify these attributes and put the Javascript inside the external `showerHider` Javascript file. Also I'm not sure if I should let the Javascript handle the transition or use CSS. I find the Javascript to be tricky when declaring transitions for all the major browsers and would prefer to let the CSS do it.

Comment: Cache your elements in variables, eg. `var btn = document.getElementById('btn')`

Comment: [Please be careful with w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Also using JavaScript "href" values is really a non-good way to do things.

Comment: elclanrs can you please be more descriptive?

Comment: I am very new to Javascript but not to HTML and CSS.

Comment: Your onclicks reference `hiderShower`, but your function is called `showeHider`. Probably just a typo in the quest, but stranger things have happened. Also, letting CSS handle the transition is probably going to be a lot easier. Adding / removing a class will also probably be easier than setting all of those style properties.

Comment: @Xavier by storing in a var like he did, you can then use `btn.style.top="1px";`

Comment: thank you pointy that is the purpose of this post...

Comment: I tried the class change and it works great but the transition would fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version:

```
function showeHider(floater) {
  var btn, btntxt, arrValues, strPx;

  floater.style.webkitTransition = "margin-top .25s ease-in-out 0s";

  btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btntxt = document.getElementById("btntxt");

  arrValues = (floater.style.marginTop == "-345px") ? ["25", "HIDE", "-370", "162", "-300", "135"] : ["-345", "SHOW", "20", "490", "17", "450"];
  strPx = "px";

  floater.style.marginTop = arrValues[0] + strPx;
  btntxt.innerHTML = arrValues[1] + " NAVIGATION";
  btntxt.style.top = arrValues[2] + strPx;
  btntxt.style.left = arrValues[3] + strPx;
  btn.style.top = arrValues[4] + strPx;
  btn.style.left = arrValues[5] + strPx;
}
```

Maybe the `strPx` was an overkill, but if you ever plan on minimizing the code, that var will only be 1 char length and there should be some gain.

**What I did was:**

- cache the elements `btn` and `btntxt`
- put the values on an array
- use the ternary operator `a ? b : c`, meaning if the stuff in `a` is true it will pick `b` otherwise `c`, you can [read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

However, consider strongly in having two classes, and then use JavaScript only to toggle between them, as Jeff Powers [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134029/908879).

Comment: Thank you this makes sense. The variables are undefined then the id's are called.

Comment: Is the '?' an operator? Does it compare?

Comment: Also how do I call the function without Javascript in my href attribute.?

Comment: Thank you so much I asm starting to really understand now. So am I forced then to use onclick value I have been using or can I do this:



'<a onclick="hiderShower()"></a>'

Comment: In response to toggling between two classes I tried that and my transition would fail.

Comment: ...and I really thought that would be an easier way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Move all of your CSS to a CSS File and nest it under a show-nav class and just toggle that on a parent element.

Also the onclick attribute was made for running javascript functions on click you should remove your javascript from the href attribute that is for linking to other pages.

```
   <a id="btntxt" href="#" onclick="hiderShower(document.getElementById('wrappernav'));">HIDE NAVIGATION</a>
```

I know you don't want to use jQuery but that helps with separation of concerns. Generally you don't want calls to javascript in your html. You would bind that with an event listener from your javascript file.

Here is a link to another question that shows how to toggle a class with vanilla javascript and jQuery if you decide to use that.

[Can this jQuery be done in vanilla JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874006/can-this-jquery-be-done-in-vanilla-js)

Comment: Can i tie my function to a Psuedo class?

Comment: Jut Css for the styles and transition would be greaqt!

Comment: I see. I thought I was using the onclick. haha Definitely will do.

Comment: But wont the href="#"stop my transition from happening?

Comment: No that will allow you to have the default cursor pointer default for links with out linking to a new page. The transition is entirely css put that in your css file like so. #floater { transition: 0.25 margin-top ease; -webkit-transition: 0.25 .... etc. }